# Continually fill colum values based on others

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, validation

I have a dataframe with few columns. One columns contain  name of employee and other column contain saraily.we have one more column called status in which data are not there in that column .That is feilds in that column is empty.
Using  panda i need to check whether all the data in the salary column is integer.if all field in salary column is integer ,then it should show true in the status columns of that particular row.if any of the field contain other than integer like 6LKH it shold show false  in the status filed if corresponding row

I konow how to.fill a na values but i dont know how to fill new column based on valy  of another columns

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please provide us with a Minimal Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) is one of the methods you can use, but we can't suggest a best-suited approach since we can't tell exactly what type of data you're working with - you should include a sample of your DataFrame so we can reproduce it; if you paste the output of `print(df.sample(10).to_markdown())` into your q, 10 rows from your df will be rendered as a table, or if you include whatever is returned by `df.sample(10).to_dict('tight')` we could use that to reproduce 10 rows from your DataFrame exactly